# SQL injection on fixed value?

Tags: mysql

I'm aware that if you're inserting a variable, it is always good to use mysqli_real_escape_string. But, if I'm inserting a fixed value which is not a variable, do I need to use that function?

For example, like the syntax below. I insert a name which is a variable, and also a value '1' into the status column. Is it safe to do that to avoid SQL injection for the column status? since it is not a variable.

```
"INSERT INTO customer(name, status) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $name) ."', '1')";
```

Comment: Do you know what is SQL injection?

Comment: I get the idea from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php But their examples are all on using variables.

Comment: I was busy answering another question and now when i get back the party is over, glad you got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using mysqli, it is safest to use prepared statements:

```
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO customer(name, status) 
  VALUES (?, '1')";
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
```

(See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php for the more detailed and working code).

In this you can leave static values as is, nobody can replace those. You can also alter your table:

```
ALTER TABLE customer ALTER COLUMN status DEFAULT '1';
```

Then you do not even have to set it any longer.

Comment: if I am to insert a fixed value for example, INSERT INTO customer(status) VALUES ('1').... is it necessary to use prepared statement?

Comment: No, not needed at all. The prepared statement is best when you have any dynamic variable since you do not have to think about escaping, concatenating strings and quotes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no objection and need to escape the values on constant as SQL Injection will not be done on static things..

Comment: Thanks, this is all I need to know.